# unable to run loop calculation(python)

Tags: python, loops

Trying to run the following code:

```
QPA=[4,5,6,7,8,9]
MT=[2,3,4,5,6,7]    
WH=[225,226,230,225,220,222]
Prd=[24,24,24,24,24,24]
MTBR=[7.5,8,9,7,5,6]
mean_v=[]
mean_value=[]
for q in QPA:
    for m in MT:
        for w in WH:
            for MT in MTBR:
                mean_v=q*m*w*24/(MT*1000)
                mean_value.append(mean_v)
print (mean_value)
```

Getting the following error:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Can somebody point out where am I going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: You're overwriting the value of the `MT` variable here: `for MT in MTBR:`. Choose a different variable name.

Comment: And as a side note, you probably wanna use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) instead of your nested for-loop

Comment: Right, thanks both of you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the same variable repeated twice. Can i suggest you that you use `zip` instead of using nested `for loops`. This would be a cleaner and concise implementation.

```
 QPA=[4,5,6,7,8,9]
 MT=[2,3,4,5,6,7]    
 WH=[225,226,230,225,220,222]
 Prd=[24,24,24,24,24,24]
 MTBR=[7.5,8,9,7,5,6]


 for q,m,w,mt in zip(QPA,MT,WH,MTBR):
     mean_v = q*m*w*24 / (mt*1000)
     mean_value.append(mean_v)
```

Comment: I'm not sure that using `m` twice in `q,m,w,m` will really help matters.